# Can't insert hashed data to Wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, hash

I made a function that generates a 21 digit random string using `wp_generate_password()`, hashes it using `wp_hash()`, saves the generated string to database and `return`s the hashed string. It works perfectly fine. However, I want to do the other way, instead of saving the generated random string to database, I want to save the hashed string and `return` the random string.

But it's not working. When I try to save the hashed string in database, it simply doesn't create any entry at all. Works perfectly fine if I want to save the random string.

I've tried sanitizing the hashed string, applied `strval()`, applied `$wpdb->insert` with `format` where I declared it as string. Nothing works! I've even tried to increase server resources to 4GB ram, 2Vcore Processors. Increased every php.ini resource limit to 3GB. Nothing works.

Here's the function that works perfectly. However, in this function, I want to replace `'verification_code'=>$email_verification` with `'verification_code'=>$email_verification_hashed` and it doesn't work. I want to make it work so hashed string goes to database and random string returns.

```
function generate_verification($user_id) {
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
$email_verification = wp_generate_password( 21, true, true );
$email_verification_hashed = wp_hash( $email_verification );
if (isset($user_info)) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->base_prefix.'custom_table'; //already exist        
    $user_email = $user_info->user_email;   
    $data = array('email'=>$user_email, 'verification_code'=>$email_verification, 'user_id'=>$user_id);
    $where = array('user_id'=>$user_id);
    $existing_data = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}custom_table WHERE user_id = {$user_id}";
    $existing_data_results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    if($existing_data_results > 0) {
        $wpdb->update( $table_name, $data, $where);
        return $email_verification_hashed;
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $data);
        return $email_verification_hashed;
    }   
} else {
    return 'Failed';
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, the database column was `VARCHAR(21)` while the hashed string was way longer than that. I simply changed the column to `VARCHAR(255)` and now it's working